# How to find mDNS instance name on chrome packaged apps?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, network-programming, google-chrome-app, mdns

I'm using [this example chrome app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/mdns-browser) as base to browse mDNS. It is working quite well and gives me service name and IP of the service provider but I'm unable to find the human readable service instance name.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this in a while, but have you had a chance to check out this repo?

https://github.com/agnat/node_mdns

"mdns adds multicast DNS service discovery, also known as zeroconf or bonjour to node.js. It provides an object based interface to announce and browse services on the local network."

See the docs, particularly the browser below!

http://agnat.github.io/node_mdns/user_guide.html#browser

Hope it helps!